# Are all of these sentences grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds

> 1. He was charged with killing 13 people.
> 2. He was charged with having killed 13 people.
> 3. He was charged with the crime he killed 13 people.

I suppose the phrase no. 1 is correct but the others also make sense or are they grammatically wrong?

Comment: 3 looks as if it has two main verbs in a single phrase and would benefit from some adjustment such as "that" or ";" between *crime* and *he*

Comment: 1 and 2 are both correct, but 1, out of any context, is ambiguous: it could mean 'He was assigned the task of killing 13 people.' 3 is syntactically incomplete, as Henry says; I would write 'He was charged with the crime of having killed &c'.

Answer (score 9):

1 and 2 are correct.

3 is wrong.  You could break it into two sentences:

> He was charged with the crime.  He killed 13 people.

But I think what you really mean is:

> He was charged with the crime **of killing** 13 people.

Comment: 3 is just missing a *that* after *crime* and before *he*. Whether you can skate by without it is an open question.

Comment: @tchrist My grammatical intuition tells me very clearly that *He was charged with the crime that he killed 13 people.* is wrong. I can't explain exactly why, but I'm sure it's wrong.

Comment: @Pitarou, I think it's your lexical intuition - the sentence is unidiomatic, but grammatically and syntactically unexceptionable.

Comment: @StoneyB Is this a matter that can be settled by Google NGram viewer?

Comment: @Pitarou, I'm not familiar with this tool's quirks. I ran 'charged with the crime that' vs 'charged with the crime of' and the results showed an overwhelming preponderance of the latter. That appears to confirm your intuition, and mine; but it doesn't tell us whether it's a grammatical, syntactical or lexical matter.

Comment: For the third one adding *in which* before the second *he* can fix the grammar.

Comment: For what it is worth, I agree with your version (*".. the crime of killing 13 people."*) and perhaps @Noah's, although I feel that the usage of the article *'the'* is not correct here, but even the article *'a'* would not sound right.

Comment: @Noah - 'in which' implies that he was charged with another crime (perhaps 'unlawfully discharging a firearm'?) in the course of which he killed &c. If that were the case (which seems unlikely), 'a' rather than 'the' would be called for - unless  the crime had been specified before this sentence appeared.

Comment: Hmm.  This discussion is interesting, but I think the most normal usage is "the crime of killing" so I'm going to stay with that.